# Page not found (404) with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django Framework and I'm following a tutorial based on Django 1.8.
I have Django 1.10 on my Mac OSX and I get an error : `Page not found`

I started a project which is named `"Crepes_bretonnes"` and I created an app : `"Blog"`.

The blog urls.py looks like :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.views import home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accueil/$', home),
]
```

The blog views.py looks like :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse    # Ce module permet de retourner une réponse (texte brute, HTML, JSON, ...) depuis une string

# Create your views here.

def home(request) :

    text = """<h1>Bienvenue sur mon blog ! </h1>
            <p> Edité sous Django 1.10 </p>"""
    return HttpResponse(text)
```

And the crepes_bretonnes urls.py looks like :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
]
```

However, when I'm running the server, I get this error (picture) and I don't understand why it's not working :/

[image]

As I said, I'm beginning Django so if anyone can explain me the problem ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crepes_bretonnes urls are including blog urls, so your blog urls are only visible from `blog/` url.

If you want to get to your view you need to open this url:

`/blog/accueil/`

Comment: Oh great ! Ok I understand. It was not my script which was false, but the url call ^^ Thank you :)